# Wav file from microphone on Python

Tags: python, audio, speech-recognition, wav, microphone

My project is to do speaker recognition using a microphone.

I'm using the speeh_recognition library to extract my microphone audio, but the object's class is 'speech_recognition.AudioData' and i don't know how to convert it into a wav file (in order to use librosa for example to then get audio features and maybe recognize the speaker).

Could someone please help me on that ? I have been learning Python for not so long so there might also be easier ways to do speaker recognition using a mic :)
Many thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

write audio to a WAV file:

```
with open("microphone-results.wav", "wb") as f:
    f.write(audio.get_wav_data())
```

Quoting the [doc](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/reference/library-reference.rst):

> Returns a byte string representing the contents of a WAV file
>   containing the audio represented by the AudioData instance.